# Angularjs doclick change class of the current div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

This is my angularjs doClick function and on click i want to change the class of the div which was clicked.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="a in analytics" style="background-color: {{a.Color}};"  
        ng-class="{'block1 current-block' : $index==0, 'block1' : !($index==0)}"  
        ng-click="myData.doClick(a, $event)">
<div>
```

In my angularjs code i find the current active class and remove it. This works fine but i don't know how to change the class of the current div.

How can i find and change the class of the div clicked?
(I tried using jquery(this) & $(this) but either of these don't seem to work. )

```
$scope.myData.doClick = function(a, event) 
{

    alert("clicked" + a.Color +a.Feature + " @ " + event.clientX + ": " + event.clientY);

    $scope.selectedItem = a.Feature;

    for(j=0;j<$('#divHolder div.block1').length;j++)
    {
    console.log('Inside for loop',j,$('#divHolder div.block1').length);

      if($( '#divHolder div.block1:eq('+j+')' ).hasClass( "current-block" )==1)
          {
          console.log('Inside if statement',j);

              $('#divHolder div.block1:eq('+j+')').removeClass('current-block');
              break;
          }

    }

    console.log('final css addition',$(this));
    jQuery(this).addClass('current-block');

};
```

Comment: Something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/jOKsJrM1oYcjl07UgC7W?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
ng-class="{current-block: a.Feature == $scope.selectedItem}"
```